# filtering only name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am actually using filter in my project.i pass the values into id in database.For Eg: if student name is there.i didnt store student name like "mala" .I pass the values NameId like 12,13etc.,My question is when i filter the function name it doesn't filter correctly.it shows only Id.how can i change into the name?anyone pls help me..my code is here.

```
       <div class="section">
        <% var topFunctions = Model.GroupBy(q => q.FunctionId)
                               .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                               .Take(5)
                               .Select(g => g.Key).ToList(); %>
        <h5>Function</h5>       

        <ul>
            <% foreach (var function in topFunctions)  { %>
                 <% var url = "http://localhost:55996/jb" + Djsite.Helpers.StringHelper.AssembleQueryStrings(filters) + "Fun=" + function; %>
                 <li><a href="<%: url %>"><%: function %></a></li>       
            <% } %>
        </ul>
    </div>

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using:

```
<li><a href="<%: url %>"><%: function.Name %></a></li>
```

Where .Name in `function.Name` is what you have called your user's name

**Edit**

Per your comment:

If you only send a list of keys to your view, then your `names` are not available to the view. You need to send your actual model to your view, not the keys - the keys are just keys, they don't contain any of the actual user's names. You should move your logic out of your view to help facilitate this process.

Comment: I don't think that'll work because the enumerable is a `Select` of Keys

Comment: Ah, you didn't send the appropriate information to your view then.  You need to send your actual model to your view, not the keys - the keys are just keys, they don't contain any of the actual user's names.

Answer (score 0):

First, an important advisory note: You should be doing this filtering in your controller and pushing the results into a Model type that is specifically built for this type of result.  This kind of logic, I contend, classes as business logic and so it should not be in your view.

To answer the original question, though: it all depends on whether the function's name is available in your `Model`.  If it's not then you need to get it in there.

Let's say it is, and it's available with the `FunctionName` property, you could use this:

```
Model.GroupBy(q => q.FunctionId)      
     .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())      
     .Take(5)      
     .Select(g => g.First().FunctionName).ToArray();
```

Note that I've also changed `ToList` to `ToArray` - don't create a list unless you need to modify the result afterwards.

Comment: Have to add in repository file about the function method.

Comment: Yes - basically anywhere from your controller 'down' the hierarchy and *not* in your view.

Don't get me wrong - if I'm prototyping a site or whatever, I would break this rule, but on anything that might end up actually having a lifecycle try and do it 'properly' and it saves you time in the long run.